# Matter js Body sprite not displaying in firefox

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have my matter.js code working perfectly in safari and chrome, but I have tested in firefox and it's not displaying any textures. I have no error messages. ¿Is there any way to fix it or is it something that I have missed?

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('world');
var engine = Matter.Engine.create();
var world = engine.world;
var Body = Matter.Body;
var Events = Matter.Events;
var render = Matter.Render.create({
  canvas: myCanvas,
  element: document.getElementById("world_wrapper"),
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    background: '#FFF',
    wireframes: false,
    showAngleIndicator: false
  }
});


// This is one of the bodies

var letter_t = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(window.innerWidth/2 - 300, random_y, 94, 72, {
  density: density,
  friction: friction,
  frictionAir: frictionAir,
  restitution: restitution,
  render: {
    sprite: {
      texture: 'externalassets/t.svg',
      xScale: scale,
      yScale: scale,
    }
  }
});

Matter.World.add(world, letter_t);
```

Comment: should the code in the question actually do something?

Comment: Thanks for the response @JaromandaX . Yes, it's showing some letters going from the bottom to the top colliding with each others. I have only paste the code of one of the letters (bodies).

Comment: well, the `run code snippet` produces an error in every browser - so, perhaps don't make it a code snippet, just make it code :p

Comment: yess @JaromandaX you are right. Sorry… I should have had more caution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the problem!!! And it was so clear... But I finally found it. It is just that firefox can't process svg files as a texture. In case you want to use a file with transparency just use png.

Comment: Works for me! I had an issue where it wouldn’t show at first but it was because the svg was missing `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: In general, `<svg>`'s always need some kind of width/height set, otherwise problems arise across many browsers/devices/OS's.